# How do I pull the first instance of an open orders expected receive date into a different Google sheet, comparing parts lists

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working on an inventory system in Google Sheets and I need to pull data from one sheet into another sheet within the same work book.

I have two lists of parts, one is an indented BOM, that shows quantity of parts. The other is a Purchasing/Receiving log for inventory.

I need to compare the BOM with the Purchasing sheet to find the first instance of an order for that part, then check if it is still open or not, then pull the expected delivery date into the matching row in the BOM sheet assuming that order is still open.

These are the two formula I have that are the closest.

`=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",(SUMIF('PURCHASING/RECEIVING LOG'!D:D,B:B,'PURCHASING/RECEIVING LOG'!L:L)))`

This one SUMS the date value, resulting in way off dates when converted back into a date format, but it correctly lines up all dates from PURCHASING RECEIVING, that match part name in BOM

`=IF(B:B='PURCHASING/RECEIVING LOG'!D:D,IF('PURCHASING/RECEIVING LOG'!C:C="OPEN",'PURCHASING/RECEIVING LOG'!L:L,"WRONG"),"WRONG2")`

This one correctly checks if the purchase order is open or not, but it only pulls the date if the rows match, instead of matching up the data for both columns. So if `'BOM'!B2 = 'PURCHASING RECEIVING'!D2`. I need to check if any row in `'PURCHASING RECEIVING'!D:D = 'BOM'!B2`, then `B3` then `B4` etc. Then pull the relevant information from `'PURCHASING RECEIVING'!L:L`

Neither of them pull only the first instance of a matching open order.

There are duplicate parts in both the BOM and the Purchasing sheet, since multiple machines use the same parts, and we have multiple open orders for the same parts at any given time.

Any help or if someone could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if there are any questions.

Thank you.

EDIT: Added sample sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fsrl4h__GbtHeHUCBs0PS25HR8MhWEplQ2bY-qcdWlw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share a sample spreadsheet containing your inputs and desired output and set it to public. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fsrl4h__GbtHeHUCBs0PS25HR8MhWEplQ2bY-qcdWlw/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the link. I tried to make it clear, and cut out a lot of the unimportant stuff for this specific question. 

Also added the link to my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `QUERY` on the second sheet to pull the required date, for example in cell G3, you would use:

```
=QUERY('PURCHASING RECEIVING'!$B$2:$E,"select min(E) where B = 'OPEN' and C ='"&E3&"' label min(E) ''")
```

And then drag down to the rest of the rows.

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: That works. And a lot more simple than what I was trying to do. Is the second half of that query SQL? After the comma.

Comment: It's Google's own query language, quite similar to SQL but with some keywords removed.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind for the future.